# Bounding box rotated on import

Tags: unity, blender, bounding-boxes, import

For some reason my bounding box is always tilted when i import to unity. I've checked for loose geometry and everything but there's nothing.

[image]

Comment: This white box is not a bounding box, it is the box that appears when you click the box edit mode on scene view. A bounding box is the box that represents the borders of components such as Collider and Renderer. If your character is facing +z when all rotations are 0, then there is no problem.

Comment: Here is a good summary of how to import from Blender to Unity: https://polynook.com/tutorial/how-to-export-models-from-blender-to-unity/ I will not re-summarize their steps as they put a lot of work into their tutorial and deserve the traffic for it. If the link goes down years later and you're looking at this I presume you'll still be able to access it from archive.org. That tutorial explains quite carefully how to avoid rotational issues of this nature.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not a new post but I found myself with the same problem. This situation happens when the hip bone is rotated so, you need to set it vertically. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using armature, check if you have your root bone named Root, so SkinnedMeshRenderer knows what bone to use.

Note that after renaming your bone, your possible blender animations might be broken. To fix this issue follow the instructions here

https://blenderartists.org/t/tip-fix-for-when-you-rename-a-bone-while-its-animations-retain-the-old-name/1367948

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using Blender. In Blender, make sure that the object has its rotation and scale applied to the mesh. In object mode, select the object, hit `Ctrl + A`, apply rotation and scale.

While the mesh itself may look fine in Blender, the object that holds the mesh might be rotated or scaled. Blender will export the unscaled and unrotated mesh directly from saved mesh data without the object's rotation and scale applied.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. On top of this, the skeleton attached to the player is also scaled to 100x the blender scale in unity. So if it's scale in blender is 0.5, in unity it will be 50, the mesh however is scaled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, for some reason disabling "Update when offscreen" fixed the issue, no idea why.

Comment: I was not the one who downvoted, but you should probably clarify in which program you applied this option and where to find it.

Comment: It would have to be Unity, I am not aware of an "Update when offscreen" option in Blender.